# ValidationError: ["'\n- July 9, 2022\n' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format. Is there a way to change the date format?

Tags: python, django, date, datetime

I'm scraping a website for data to include in my project and while fetching the date it comes in a mm-dd-yyyy format like so "July 9, 2022". Is there a way to bypass this and avoid the error?

```
table = soup.find_all("a", attrs = {"class": "job-details-link"})

def jobScan(link):     
    the_job = {}
    jobUrl = link['href']
    the_job['urlLink'] = jobUrl
   
    jobs = requests.get(jobUrl, headers = headers )
    jobC = jobs.content
    jobSoup = BeautifulSoup(jobC, "lxml")
    
    post_date = jobSoup.find_all("span", {"class": "job-date__posted"})[0]
    date_posted = post_date.text
    the_job['date_posted'] = date_posted

    close_date = jobSoup.find_all("span", {"class": "job-date__closing"})[0]
    closing_date = close_date.text
    the_job['closing_date'] = closing_date

    return the_job

for a in table:
    final_jobs.append(jobScan(a))    

for test_job in final_jobs:    
    newjob = Jobs.objects.create(
        title = test_job['title'],
        location = test_job['location'],
        date_posted = test_job['date_posted'],
        closing_date = test_job['closing_date'],
        )
```

the error:

ValidationError: ["'\n- July 9, 2022\n' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `strptime` function to convert your date to an actual date object, which Django will then happily accept

See these 2 sections of the Python documentation for more:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

In this instance it seems, that you can just do

```py
date_posted = datetime.strptime(test_job['date_posted'], "\n- %B %d, %Y\n")
closing_date = datetime.strptime(test_job['closing_date'], "\n- %B %d, %Y\n")
```

however additional processing of the strings may be needed if the format sligthly deviates every time

Comment: I added something to my question for more clarity, cause I tried your solution and it still raised the error.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the settings in the setting see here   https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.0/ref/settings/#date-format

Comment: jus tried adding the date_input_formats to the settings but if still raises the error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In your `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` is what you put `'%d %B, %Y'` in the first line like this:
`[
    '%d %B, %Y', # 'October 25, 2006'
    '%Y-%m-%d', # '2006-10-25'
    '%m/%d/%Y', # '25/10/2006'
    '%m/%d/%y', # '10/25/06'
    '%b %d %Y', # 'October 25, 2006'
    '%b %d, %Y', # 'October 25, 2006'
    '%d %b %Y', # 'October 25, 2006'
    '%d %b, %Y', # 'October 25, 2006'
    '%B %d %Y', # 'October 25, 2006'
    '%B %d, %Y', # 'October 25, 2006'
    '%d %B %Y', # 'October 25, 2006'
]`

Comment: ```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = [
    '%Y-%m-%d',  # '2006-10-25'
    '%m/%d/%Y',  # '10/25/2006'
    '%m/%d/%y',  # '10/25/06'
    '%b %d %Y',  # 'Oct 25 2006'
    '%b %d, %Y',  # 'Oct 25, 2006'
    '%d %b %Y',  # '25 Oct 2006'
    '%d %b, %Y', # '25 Oct, 2006'
    '%d %d %Y,'  # 'October 25 2006'
    '%B %-d, %Y',  # 'October 9, 2006'
    '%B %d, %Y',  # 'October 25, 2006'
    '%d %B %Y',  # '25 October 2006'
    '%d %B, %Y',  # '25 October, 2006'
]
```